# jQuery, select TR's in table where column 2 data is constant?

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors

I have an HTML table. I need a jQuery selector to select only the TR's, where column2 (TD) text is equal to = "foo". Is this possible?

```
 <table>
        <tr><td>asdasd</td><td>foo</td><td>fsdf</td></tr>
        <tr><td>asdasd</td><td>xxx</td><td>fsdf</td></tr>
        <tr><td>asdasd</td><td>xxx</td><td>fsdf</td></tr>
        <tr><td>asdasd</td><td>foo</td><td>fsdf</td></tr>
        <tr><td>asdasd</td><td>foo</td><td>fsdf</td></tr>
    </table>
```

so the selector should return rows 1,4, and 5. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks a bunch,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: I used a variation of the answers provided and i get the result I am looking for.
var selector = $("table tr").filter(function(index) { return $(this).text().indexOf("foo")!=-1; });

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr').filter(function(index){
    return this.cells[1].innerHTML === 'foo';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My jQuery may be a little rusty, but does something like this work for you?

```
$('table tr td:eq(1)').filter(function(index) {
    return $(this).text() === 'foo';
});
```

Comment: This will be dramatically slower.

Answer (score 0):

so it might be shortened a little work time:

```
$("table tr").each(function(){
    if( $(this).text().indexOf("foo")!=-1 ) {
        var el = $('td:eq(1)', $(this));
        if (el.text() == 'foo')
            el.attr("bgcolor", "#336699"); //test
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'foo' doesn't have to be in column 2 and just needs to be in the row, you can use this selector as well (I'm just adding this for completeness).

```
$('tr:contains("foo")').filter(function(index){ return $(this) });
```